# Delphi TZip failing if archive contains > 64k files

Tags: delphi, zip

I just hit what appears to be an annoying limitation in Delphi.

My archive has 117,898 files in it (they're all 256x256 JPEG images so stored without ZIP compression - ZIPs just a delivery mechanism)

Anyway, I just moved up from my previous ZIP which had 24,989 images to the new one and it stops at 65536 files (i.e. index = 65535) then Range errors on me.

It, therefore appears that TZip is 16 bit (or I'm doing something emensely stupid)

I just discovered that Delphi 11 has 64 bit support - but that's also limited to  64k files

Comment: "*Delphi 11 has 64 bit support - but that's also limited to 64k files*" - it shouldn't be. `TZipFile` was [updated in Delphi 11](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/What%27s_New#RTL:_TZipFile) to support the Zip64 format, which allows for more files, larger archives, etc.

Answer (score 2):

That is not an annoying Delphi limitation, but a limitation of the ZIP specification as can be seen here: [APPNOTE.TXT](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)

In section 4.3.16 the *total number of entries in the central directory* has only 2 bytes.

Comment: Version 4.5 of the ZIP spec introduced the Zip64 format, which removes that limitation (amongst others). `TZipFile` was [updated in Delphi 11](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/What%27s_New#RTL:_TZipFile) to support Zip64.

Answer (score 2):

> That is not an annoying Delphi limitation, but a limitation of the ZIP specification as can be seen here: APPNOTE.TXT
>
> In section 4.3.16 the total number of entries in the central directory has only 2 bytes.

In the original version of the Zip spec there is indeed a limitation of 2 bytes for the number of files in the zip archive, but that has been superseded for a very long time. Below if from [APPNOTE.TXT](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) version 6.3.9

```
   4.4.21 total number of entries in the central dir on 
          this disk: (2 bytes)
 
      The number of central directory entries on this disk.
      If an archive is in ZIP64 format and the value in 
      this field is 0xFFFF, the size will be in the 
      corresponding 8 byte zip64 end of central 
      directory field.
```

If Delphi TZip supports the Zip64 spec, it should be able to store more than 64k files. Given your experience I suspect it doesn't

**[EDIT]**

The link provided by Remy Lebeau regarding the update to `TZipFile`, [here](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/What%27s_New#RTL:_TZipFile), says this about support for Zip64

```
RTL: TZipFile
... We added support for Zip64 and ... works with files larger in size than 4 GB.
```

While it does mention support for `Zip64`, it doesn't explicitly mention support for having more than 64k files.

Comment: Delphi's `TZipFile` was [updated in Delphi 11](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/What%27s_New#RTL:_TZipFile) to support the Zip64 format.

Comment: @RemyLebeau While the statement is nice and all, have you checked? It is Embarcadero we are talking about, right?

Comment: At first glance the implementation of TZipFile.ReadCentralHeader does seem off. LHeader64.CentralDirEntries seems not to be filled with a 64Bit value.

Comment: Sherlock70 can you share a link to the source for `TZipFile.ReadCentralHeader` please?

Comment: TZip does look to have a limit of ~2 billion files due to storing/returning a file count in an integer. Ex. `function GetFileCount: Integer`  It does use a central directory definition with a `CentralDirEntries:   UInt64` line. Not sure if the ~2 billion file limitation is a problem in practice even though Zip64 supports much more..

Comment: @pmqs `TZipFile` is part of Embarcadero's RTL, there is no link to view it online. But you should have it in your IDE installation in `$(BDS)\source\rtl\common\System.Zip.pas`.

Comment: Thanks Remy, but I don't use delphi

Comment: @pmqs its with the sources of a non-CE install. I don't believe I may distribute the sources any other way.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little test program that creates 70,000 1 byte files in a zip file. Delphi 11.2 successfully creates the 70,000 files in the zip file.  In the test program I also made it read the file that had been created. It successfully read the 70,000 1 byte files.

I had a look at the differences in system.zip  for Delphi 11 and while there are some changes... I don't think it would affect working with large numbers of files in the zip.

Answer (score 0):

I learned recently (last week) that TZipFile now supports extraction of Zip & Zip64 format content. This is with bcc32 in C++ Builder 11.3.1.

I have also verified that TZipFile does NOT currently support insertion of Zip64 format content using bcc32 in C++ Builder 11.3.1.

When I do Zip->Add(FileName, String(), zcDeflate64);
Add() throws EZipException& E where E.Message = L"Support for compression method not registered: Deflated64";
This is with bcc32 in C++ Builder 11.3.1.

I have not yet tested extraction of Zip64 format content using Android32 clang or iOS64 clang in C++ Builder 11.3.1.